# I want to make an "ADDRESS" result in Excel readable as an array in MDETERM

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to calculate matrix determinants (using the function "`MDETERM`"), the size of which are contingent on the value AL33 in the example below. I can use either the Excel 2010 row number/column number method for "address" or the "cell(address..." technique (as I've done below) to get the references I would like to put into the array for the `MDETERM` function, but apparently the references are only seen as text, and when I try as a formula:

```
=MDETERM(CELL("address",INDEX(AJ39:AS39,11-MATCH(AL33,AS39:AS48))):CELL("address",INDEX(AS39:AS48,MATCH(AL33,AS39:AS48))),
```

I get the message "`the formula you typed has an error`"

I use 2010, and have tried different methods with the EVAL (both with and without VBA) function in an attempt to make the address result "readable", but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence, *"Use INDIRECT when you need to convert a reference assembled as text into a proper reference,"* from [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/formula/create-array-of-numbers) turned the light on for me about the `INDIRECT` function - it makes the references obtained from the `CELL("address", [reference])` command usable in this amended formula:

`=MDETERM(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(AJ39:AS39,11-MATCH(AL33,AS39:AS48)))):INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(AS39:AS48,MATCH(AL33,AS39:AS48)))))`

Comment: Hi. Be aware of the volatile nature of the `INDIRECT` function. Try to have as few of those as possible, or your spreadsheet will become very performance hungry.